# Trouble creating new Exchange Server account in Lion

Tags: email, exchange

I'm helping a colleague set up his new MBA. When we try to create his email account in mail.app, we choose Exchange but the auto-discover feature fails to start.

It has worked fine for 4 others in the office so we know our Exchange 2007 server is programmed to support auto-discovery.

When we try to manually enter the server settings, he can receive email but not send.

I know that auto-discover prompts for userid, password and domain. When we enter the data manually, we can't find a place to enter the domain. Is this why he can't send email?

What else can we try?  Is this an Apple issue since auto-discovery doesn't start?

Comment: Have you tried to use your exchange server as SMTP? To connect to our Exchange server I input no domain information (only login/password). And I've used SMTP with NTLM auth when we've used Exchange 2003.

Comment: Yeah you generally dont need to enter the domain. Any specific error messages? Anything in the Console when he is unable to send?

Comment: When I manually add the same server info from our other Macs, the outgoing message fails.  The only accounts that send and receive are the ones that were created using auto setup including the domain. I haven't checked the console log but I will.

Comment: The genius bar figured out how to enable auto discovery to work and now it prompted for the login, password and domain that my company's server required.  Thanks to those who posted comments @Eir Nym

Comment: I glad to read this!

Comment: It would be great if bg2011 could share the solution. Im having a very similar problem: autodiscovery doesnt work, but i cant receive or send mail if i manually enter all the information. MS Outlook works fine though.
Also Mail was working (with autodiscovery) 3h earlier, and i have not, consciously, changed a setting. My colleague can set up his Mail using autodiscovery.

Comment: Hi @durd  I was stumped too and the genius at the apple store did some things with my mac and autodiscovery resumed.  In mail.app, I added an account, choose exchange and it prompted me in sequence for login, password and domain.  It went on to verify the account and I was all set.